# How can I access a div from another div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent

```html
<div id="a">
  <div id="b">
      <div id="c"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="a2"></div>
</div>
```

I want from div where `id="c"` to access div where `id="a2"`, but it's not working:

```js
$("#c").parentsUntil("#a").find("#a2");
```

Comment: Try closest() instead. 
$(“#c”).closest(“#a”).find('#a2');

Comment: @TrầnQuangSơn thanks bro <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation for `parentsUntil`](https://api.jquery.com/parentsuntil/):

> Get the ancestors of each element in the current set of matched elements, up to **but not including** the element matched by the selector, DOM node, or jQuery object.

What this means is that `parentsUntil` is returning all of the parents of `#c` *except for* `#a`.  (Which in this case is just `#b`.)  And none of those elements contain `#a2`.  Use `closest` instead:

```js
$("#c").closest("#a").find("#a2").css('color', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a">
  <div id="b">
    <div id="c">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="a2">
    test
  </div>
</div>
```